# Best approach to stop a thread that's downloading a file

Tags: python, multithreading, pyside

I'm using PySide, and running downloads on secondary threads, so that the UI doesn't block.

It's just basically a button that starts the download on a new thread and saves the file to disk. I'd like to have a "cancel" button that stops the download. I've looked up ways to stop threads, but they seem hackish and look like something that shouldn't really be done.

If thread stopping is hackish, what is the proper way of doing this? It's obviously done in hundreds of software. Maybe with a flag? My thread looks something like this. Once it's started, I don't know how to "pause" it or stop it.

```
goOn = True

def MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, url):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.url = url

    def run(self):
        data = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url)
        f = open('fileName', 'wb')
        size = int(data.headers['Content-Length'])
        downloaded = 0
        blockSize = 1024 * 8
        while True:
            buffer = data.read(blockSize)
            if not buffer:
                break
            f.write(buffer)
            downloaded += blockSize
            '''
            if not goOn: # Something like this?
                break
            '''
```

Thanks.

Comment: Closing 'data' from another thread may well generate an exception in the thread.  Worth trying if you don't want to poll flags.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Do you mean the data object obtained from urllib? Thanks.

Comment: FYI you probably want to use urllib3 over urllib as the former is thread-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, url):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.url = url

    def run(self):
        data = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url)
        f = open('fileName', 'wb')
        size = int(data.headers['Content-Length'])
        downloaded = 0
        blockSize = 1024 * 8
        self.running = 1
        while self.running:
            buffer = data.read(blockSize)
            if not buffer:
                break
            f.write(buffer)
            downloaded += blockSize
    def stop_running(self):
        self.running =0
```

should work I think ...

Comment: So basically a flag is the best way of doing this, and the way that it is generally done?

Comment: yeah its a common way of accomplishing this